# Асинхронная загрузка initialState в Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, асинхронность, redux, redux-toolkit

Нужно загружать данные с сервера, которые потом должны попасть в redux store, использую Redux Toolkit. Первый вопрос, могу ли я просто в корневом компоненте типа App сделать useEffect, внутри него fetch а там в then я просто диспатчу экшн который засетит нужные поля полученными данными ? Т.е вопрос в том, корректно ли это(вопрос не про то, что это может не очень хорошо, ведь у редакса свои штуки есть для этого, вопрос именно "будет ли это правильно работать в 100% случаях") ? И второй вопрос, как бы вы это реализовали - любой способ / инструмент в рамках React + Redux ?

Comment: Вот статейка на тему "React + Redux обработка запросов" - https://ru.hexlet.io/courses/js-redux-toolkit/lessons/async-thunks/theory_unit

Comment: вам даже в then не надо ничего сетить. компонент все равно перерисуется при изменении стейта. т.о. вы просто фетчите данные и выводите их.